# Reduce number of allocations in matrix multiplication in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

Is there any way to reduce the number of allocations when multiplying matrices in Julia? I would like to reduce this number if possible. I have attached a screenshot that displays this.

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 3):

You can go down to no allocations if you pre-allocate the output matrix:

```
julia> x = rand(600, 600);

julia> y = rand(600, 600);

julia> z = zeros(600, 600);

julia> @allocated mul!(z, x, y)
0
```

Comment: Does this improve speed as well?

Comment: time will be about the same.

Comment: unless you do millions of small multiplications. Then in-place variant will be preferred as it will lead to lower garbage collection time.